# RegEx for finding two separate pieces of data in a block of text

Tags: regex

Looking for a regular expression to find the words: David and 07888998 per line, They can be found more than once.

This is the data:

```
abcasdahadMichaeljkhdkjh 0888881SNADNA
SSMA,DAAASDDDavidjhsjdha007888998
asdsdASDDDavidjhsjdha==007888998asffafa
asdsdASDDDavidjhsjdha==007888995asffafa
SSMA|DAAASDDDaidjhsjdha007888998
```

The regular expression should find 2 matches. Line 2 and Line 3.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do they need to be in that order?

Comment: Can be in any order, this is a snippet of what is produced.

Answer (score 3):

Since the order does not matter, you can use positive lookahead assertion (assuming the language/tool you are using supports it) as:

```
^(?=.*David)(?=.*07888998).*$
```

[**Rubular link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/fE1kaj5gZa)

Comment: @sin: Will do but OP also wanted to match the entire line that matches.

Comment: Whats the difference between your answer(thanks btw) and sin's response?

Answer (score 0):

If order matters, then `/David.*07888998/` will find the matches you want.

If it doesn't matter and you want to make sure they both appear at least once, you can just "or" together two regexes that account for either order:  `/(David.*07888998|07888998.*David)/`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/(David.*07888998)|(07888998.*David)/
```

Comment: has exactly the same answer not been posted 5 minutes before yours?

Comment: It was posted between when I started typing and hit post.

Answer (score 0):

More ways:

`^(?=.*David)(?=.*07888998)`
or
`(?:.*(?!\1)(David|07888998)){2}`
or
`(.*(?!\2)(David|07888998)){2}`